# how to debug crash on iphone for javascript app

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, exc-bad-access, segmentation-fault, kern-invalid-address

I am new to performance and memory leaks in JavaScript and `wkwebview`. How to find the memory leak in JavaScript app that runs on iPhone?  My app crashes with exception `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`, subtype-  `(KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the name of the function you're calling, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck! Add some more code so that it can rightly be solved.

Comment: Thanks bozzmob, unfortunately I am not sure where the issue might in the code and I am trying to figure out ways and tools to start of the investigation.